# Find a conformal mapping which....

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a conformal mapping which reflects the $|z|=1$ and $|z+2|=1$ circles in concentric circles with a center at the $z=2$ point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is clearly impossible. The point $z=-1$ belongs to both circles, so assuming $\varphi$ is the wanted conformal mapping, $\varphi(-1)$ must simultaneously belong to two concentric circles.

Comment: Thanks, it was probably a mistake in the textbook. But in general, how can I find a conformal mapping that reflects two circles on concentric ones, when I know both the equations of the circles and the center of the concentric ones?

Comment: @Kushtrim: Assuming that two circles do not intersect, you may use a circular inversion, mapping them into a circle and an external line. Can you solve the problem in this simpler setting?

Comment: We haven't mentioned anything about circular inversion in class. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Kushtrim: it is just the map $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z-z_0}$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a book/blog-post that has some similar exercises?

Comment: @Kushtrim: a good practice may be to study the circular inversion in Euclidean geometry (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Circle.shtml) then translate the results in terms of conformal mappings $z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  (see, for instance, www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~sb/CA_sectionIVnotes.pdf)